# Several TableView questions

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am looking to create a similar interface to the iTunes iPhone app search interface. I have a few questions I can't seem to find an answer for:

Here is an image of the iTunes iPhone app search interface in question:

[image]

- How do I create the tableView section subtitle, e.g. the `Tap to Preview, Double-Tap to View info` under the `Top Hits` section title.
- How is the price button created to float right? Is this done natively or using a custom UIView?
- Finally how would I differentiate between a single tap and double tap on any of the table view cells?

Comment: Thanks for actually linking an image :). good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a Custom UITableViewCell, [here's a tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/). for the price button and other visuals of the cell.

As for the `Tap to Preview` subtitle, you can create a custom header view, see:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Most likely, you would need to create 2 `UILabels` for this view, and obviously you would want to match the fonts used here.

### An Example

```
- (UIView *) tableview:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];  

    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    label.text = @"Top Hits";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    [headerView addSubview:label];

    UILabel * label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    label2.text = @"Tap to Preview, Blah blah blah";
    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Apple's Default Font?" size:17];
    [headerView addSubview:label2];

    /*  something like this  */
    return headerView;
}
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of your questions are address well in Apple's [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451). Here are some short answers:

1. You can make a header for a section be a `UIView`, in which case you can use multiple `UILabel`s to create titles with subtitles and the like.
2. This is probably set as the `accessoryView` of the `UITableViewCell`, or it may be an entirely custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`.
3. For this, you'll need to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. For more on customizing this method (e.g. to differentiate between single and mutliple taps), check out the [Managing Selections](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9) section of the above tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

1-For the Custom header
you can use the table view datasource method
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

and then you can either create the view programmtically with all the labels
or you can make an seperate view in the xib ,create its instance in your viewcontroller and return that instance in the above datasource method- this approach would be much easier and simpler.

2- You can implement the price button by using a uibutton and setting it an background image
in a custom table view cell. you can hide/unhide this button as per your functionality.

3- I would suggest you to disable the tableview selection and add tap gesture recognizers to the custom table view cell. this would give you more flexibility

Hope this could help you